# How can I create a List of a custom class with two fields and get output?

Tags: java, arrays, class, list, input

I need to make list of a gene sequence in Java and the starting positions of the parts that I care. I use a .txt file as input then search "GT" in the sequence. Once I find it, I want to store it in an array with the corresponding index. I couldn't make it happen. Please guide me.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


class Signal{
    public String signal;
    public int  pos;
    public Signal(String s, int p) {
        s = signal;
        p = pos;

    }


public static String inputSequence(String filename) throws IOException{


        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));

        try {
            FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
            MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());

    return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();

}
        finally{
            stream.close();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     String c1 = "GT";
     String seq = null;
         List<Signal> s2 = new ArrayList<Signal>();
         String s1;
         int i;

         try {
            seq = inputSequence(path);
         } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Signal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
         for (i = 0; i < seq.length() - 2; i++ ) {
     s1 = seq.substring(i,i+2);
        if (s1.equals(c1)){

            Signal ss = new Signal(s1, i);
            s2.add(ss);

}

    }
         System.out.print(s2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to explain exactly what you couldn't get working so people can look at a specific problem.

Comment: Actually this builds successfully but I can not get the output I want.
I'm trying to make it as an arrayList of Signal class I want to get an output like this: 

[(GT,5), (GT,12), (GT,27)] 

But, I'm getting this: [signal.Signal@42e816]

I need to figure out storing two fields(one string, one integer) in the List<Signal>

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor should be as follows:

```
public Signal(String s, int p) {
    signal = s;
    pos = p;
}
```

After that it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks AnshulGarg, but that is not a solution for my problem. In my comment to dogbane, I explained a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` in a loop to find all occurrences of "GT". This is shown below:

```
 String c1 = "GT";
 String seq = null;
 List<Signal> s2 = new ArrayList<Signal>();

 try {
    seq = inputSequence(path);
 } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Signal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }

 int index = seq.indexOf(c1, 0);
 do{
      if(index != -1){
          Signal ss = new Signal(c1, index);
          s2.add(ss);
          System.out.println(index);
      }
      index = seq.indexOf(c1, index+2);
 }while(index != -1);

 System.out.println(s2);
```

To print out the signals list you need to override `toString` in your `Signal` class:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "(" + signal + "," + pos + ")";
}
```

Comment: thanks dogbane, it is my bad that couldn't explain my problem completely.
I'm finding all the "GT"s. However, I'm trying to make it as an arrayList of Signal class

I want to get an output like this:


[(GT,5), (GT,12), (GT,27)]

But I'm getting this:

[signal.Signal@42e816]

Comment: I've a question dogbane, what if I want to check for two Strings in the sequence like

c1 = "GT"
c2 = "ATG"

Comment: You should create a method which takes in c1 as the argument and returns a list of signals. You can then call this method with "GT" and then again with "ATG".

Comment: Could you help me little bit more please, I know I might be asking too much but I really am a rookie in programming and not good at self education.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try not to use ArrayList.

You can try making your own class:

```java
 public class ArraySignals {
      public ArraySignals(Signal ...signals){ s = signals...; } // assigns to array
      private Signal[] s = new Signal[];    // uninitialized
      // ... ...
      @Override public String toString() {     String str = "["
        for (Signal sig : s) {    // for-each loop / range-base for loop
          str += sig.toString() + ", ";
        }
      }
    }
```

Since in java, you can't specialize templates (as there are none; there are only generics), this is a suitable option.

If you do not know (yet) what generics are, don't worry!